# transferring control from one button to another

Tags: javascript, html

I want to switch control on button click like if I press button 1, button 2 should stop working and if I press button 2, button 1 should stop working.

Here is http://jsfiddle.net/6xuDh/2/ the code I am working on
one button 1. I am drawing something but on pressing button 2 I want to do something else but right now once I press button 1 it does not lose the control

```
<input id="lineDraw" type="button"  onclick="onButtonClick()" value ="wall"/>

<input id="door" type="button"  onclick="onButtonClick()"  value ="door"/>

document.getElementById("door").onclick = function(){

}

document.getElementById("lineDraw").onclick = function() {
    }
```

Comment: Have the handler for one button set the `disabled` property of the other button.

Comment: document.getElementById("door").onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById("lineDraw").onclick = function() {return false;}
    alert(this.id);
}

document.getElementById("lineDraw").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("door").onclick = function() {return false;}
    alert(this.id);
}

tried doing this does not work

Comment: Please don't try to put long codes in comments. There's no formatting so they're unreadable. Add an update to your question. And I don't see what that code has to do with my suggestion to disable the button.

Comment: nvm it has been resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Vsesb/

Reading the FabricJS Documentation, you'll see that Canvas extends StaticCanvas which has the Observable Mixin http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Observable.html

The key here is to detach the events you are attaching handlers to by using the `off` function. Calling this without a handler reference (2nd argument) clears all attached handlers. You can call this in a centralized function for every button click as show. I hope you get the idea. Good luck!

```
function clearEvents(){
  canvas.off('mouse:down');
  canvas.off('mouse:move');
  canvas.off('mouse:up');
}
document.getElementById("door").onclick = function(){
  clearEvents();
  ...
}
```

Also a minor addition, you don't need the inline onButtonClick() as you are attaching to the onclick event in your JS code.

Comment: Thanx a ton man i am still new fabricjs THAT WAS AWESOME ^_^
thankyou